# How to compose XlaComputation?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

How do I use an `XlaComputation` when building another `XlaComputation`? For example, I want to build `Add` into a computation, which I'm trying to do as

```
xla::XlaBuilder add_builder("Add");
auto one = ConstantR0(&add_builder, 1);
auto two = ConstantR0(&add_builder, 2);
auto sum = Add(one, two);
add_builder.Build();

xla::XlaBuilder mul_builder("Mul");
auto three = ConstantR0(&mul_builder, 3);
auto res = Mul(sum, three);
mul_builder.Build();
```

but I get

> Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Invalid argument: XlaOp with handle 3 is built by builder 'Add', but is trying to use it in builder 'Mul':

I'm aware I'm not supposed to use an `XlaOp` from one builder in another computation, but I don't understand how to avoid that when that `XlaOp` corresponds to the result of that computation. After reading the following comment in the source code

```
// This represents an instruction that has been enqueued using the XlaBuilder.
// This is used to pass to subsequent computations that depends upon the
// instruction as an operand.
class XlaOp {
```

I'm guessing that only applies to `XlaOp`s using the same builder.